# Pagination links not working

Tags: pagination

I have deployed pagination to one of templates which should to display only 4 products on a page. Index for that template looks like:

```
{embed="includes/.header-product" body_color="#FFFFFF"}

        {if segment_3}{embed="includes/.nav-main"}{product}{/if}
        {if segment_2 && segment_3==""}{embed="includes/.nav-main-subcategory"}{subcategory}{/if}
        {if segment_1 && segment_2==""}{embed="includes/.nav-main"}{category}{/if}


{embed="includes/.footer"}
```

Switchee version of code above:

```
{embed="includes/.header-product" body_color="#FFFFFF"}


    {!-- Category view --}
    {if segment_1 && segment_2==""}{embed="includes/.nav-main"}{category}
        {!-- /Category view --}
    {if:else}

        {exp:switchee variable="{segment_3}" parse="inward"}

        {case value="#^P(\d+)$#|''"}
                {embed="includes/.nav-main-subcategory"}{embed="furniture/.subcategory"}
        {/case}

        {!-- Subcategory view --}
            {case value=""}
                {embed="includes/.nav-main-subcategory"}{embed="furniture/.subcategory"}
            {/case}
            {!-- /Subcategory view --}

            {!-- Single product view --}        
            {case default="Yes"}
                {embed="includes/.nav-main"}{product}
            {/case}
            {!-- /Single product view --}

        {/exp:switchee}
    {/if}

{embed="includes/.footer"}
```

and subcategory snippet code looks like:

```
<div class="container category">

    <div class="row row-category">

    {exp:channel:entries channel="products" category="{segment_2_category_id}" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="4" paginate="bottom" dynamic="no"}

        {if no_results}
                <div class=""><p>No entries yet.</p></div>
            {/if}

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 category-item">
                <a href="{site_url}{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{url_title}">
        {product_image limit="1"}
                <img src="{product_image:image}" alt="{product_image:title}" class="img-responsive">
        {/product_image}    
                <h3>{title}</h3>
                </a>
            </div>

    {switch='|||</div><div class="row row-category">'}


    {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

   </div><!--/row-->


</div><!--/container-->
```

First page is OK but other pages comes blank. I think I have done something wrong within index or template structure for furniture group but no clue what can be wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What do the URLs generated by the pagination links looked like? Also: holy embeds, this template terrifies me.

Comment: Links look like http://www.domain.com/furniture/chairs/P4 Also this is my 3rd EE site and 1st building from scratch. All my EE knowledge comes from that book: http://mijingo.com/products/books/expressionengine-2-quickstart-guide/

Comment: Is there any other way to manage category/subcategory/product not using URL segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that the conditional that you're using to insert your "subcategory" is getting tripped up by the presence of the segments that pagination would automatically create - segment 3 for example might be blank on your index view, but once you paginate, it's likely occupied, and as such, the terms of your condition can't be met and therefore your listing embed isn't being inserted at all.  You may have an easier time with it if you use the excellent [switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) add-on which could parse your conditionals earlier using switch case and allow you to detect pagination segments using regex (see the example on the devot-ee page for details).

And to Derek's point - if you don't need an embed - which you would only need if you have a need to either pass a variable (which you're not doing, based on your code), or work around native parse order  - you likely could do the same thing with snippets instead and save on performance.

Comment: I thought that it must be something with that index file at the first point. Regarding using snippets it is good idea, but as I mentioned above my knowledge about EE comes from that book. But it is not too late to learn proper way ;)

Comment: When moved code to snippet if no_results is not working. Any clue?